# Error loading data in Db2 on IBM Cloud due implicit schema creation

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

i am not able to load data to the cloud from source table to target table getting following error

> Error for batch element #1: "NPG23255" does not have the privilege to
> perform operation "IMPLICIT CREATE SCHEMA".. SQLCODE=-552,
> SQLSTATE=42502, DRIVER=4.26.14 Number of occurrences: 1

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are either using the [Lite plan](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Db2onCloud?topic=Db2onCloud-free_plan) and / or you do not have been granted the right set of privileges.

When on the Lite plan for Db2 on Cloud, you are only allowed to use the assigned database schema. You cannot create a new schema, either directly or implicitly. If you are loading data into FOO.BAR and you can only work with schema FOO2, it would give the above error message.

The reason is that you don't have the privilege to create a new schema. If you are using a paid plan, then the administrator has not granted that privilege to you and you would need to follow up.